# How to Start withHadoop in Oracle Virtual box

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I have configured Hadoop with a Hortonworks Sandbox and mounted it with Oracle Virtual Box. Now when I am starting the virtual box machine, the Linux system for Hadoop is booting up and there is an option Alt+F5 for start. But when I press Alt+F5, it asks me for a username and password.

I haven't specified any username/password during the time of installation when the virtual box is starting the Hortonworks Sandbox is running locally on my machine. So I am confident that my Hadoop is installed successfully.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login/SSH to the hadoop with the below credentials

- hue/hadoop
- root/hadoop

I've listed out these and other handy URL's that can help you get started in my (full disclosure) [blog here](http://2scompliment.wordpress.com/). Go through it if you are interested.

Comment: thanks a lot i have logged into hadoop shell but i am a  bit little confused about the things that in this tutorial some urls are listed but these urls are not resulting in my localhost.should i type then into hadoop shell??

Comment: @lucifer were you able to login to the sandbox at all from the browser? Ask the questions as comments on the blog with specific url's.

Comment: yah i was able to run sandbox in mozila and chrome

Comment: @lucifer Which URL isn't working for you? For Hbase related URL's to work you need to enable it first in the Sandbox. This isn't wnabled by default.

Comment: what do you mean by i need to enable this URL to sandbox??

Answer (score 0):

For Hortonworks Sandbox the default username and password if I remember correctly is root/hadoop. Hope this helps.

Comment: That should be correct looking at http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/shell-login-passwords/